# Query using xquery and SQL on an sql table

Tags: xpath, xquery-sql

I have an **sql** table with *3 columns* and one of the columns is *xml*. Some of the elements in the xml are duplicates.

How do I query the table where the xml elements occur more than once??

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Answer (score 0):

In the case of:

- your table has a primary key (`id` here in sample)
- your xml data are generated by program (so no tab, space, carriage return inserted by human)

I think, you can try to use the following query to find duplicate :

```
SELECT *
FROM <table> AS t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
        FROM <table> AS t2
        WHERE t2.Id <> t1.Id
            AND CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),t2.<xmlcol>) = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),t1.<xmlcol>))
```